# Dynamic Content Slide Animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am visualizing a JavaScript/CSS animation to bring some movement to an otherwise static page displaying data. But struggle with the code.

**The Background**
A JSON file is read every couple of minutes and its data extracted into a JS array from which each item is added as child `div` element to the parent `div` on the page.

**The Intended Outcome** (similar to perhaps phone notifications)

[image: Gif animation of the outcome]

**Order of Events**

1. The first array item gets added to the `div` container (using a slide in from right animation) as can be seen in the demo above.
2. When the next item is added (i.e. next array element) everything on the visible HTML "stack" shifts down by 1 height, making room for the next item (I think JQuery's `div.children()` selector would come in handy here).
3. The item now slides into the space on top.
4. If the "stack" already contains 4 elements, yet another needs to be added as it hasn't reached the end of the array, the oldest item should slide out to the right (as shown when item 1 slides out, making room for item 5) - simply put, keeping the total visible elements at 4.

**The Problem**
I am able to add the JSON data to the column but have never been able to make any successful animations. So far, I have looked into animation libraries and other posts but no success, nothing comes close to what I am trying to achieve. I would appreciate it if somebody could help me out with the animation when items get added/shifted/removed.

**The Code**

```js
var allRecents = []; // Master List
(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'recent.json', // LINK TO JSON FILE HERE
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.recent.length > 0 || allRecents.length > 0) {
                // Remove Empty Message
                $('#emptyMessage').remove();

                // Pull Recent Additions From JSON File
                var justAdded = [];
                for (r in data.recent) {
                    //console.log("++++++ NEW JSON ELEMENT ++++++");
                    var title = data.recent[r].title;
                    var added = data.recent[r].added;
                    var type = data.recent[r].type;

                    // Color-coded Elements
                    if (type == 'Movie') {
                        var color = 'crimson';
                    } else {
                        var color = 'darkorchid';
                    }
                    
                    justAdded.push([title, added, type]);

                    // DOM Element to Add
                    var block = '<div id="recent-media" class="info-container '
                        + color + '"><div class="when center"><h4>'
                        + added + '</h4></div><div class="what"><h4>'
                        + title + '</h4></div></div>'
                
                    var alreadyAdded = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < allRecents.length; i++) {
                        if (title == allRecents[i][0]) {
                            alreadyAdded = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (alreadyAdded == false) {
                        allRecents.push([title, added, type]);
                        if ($('.list').length) {
                            $('.list').prepend(block);
                        } else {
                            $('.list').append(block);
                        }
                        
                        console.log("Item " + title + " has been added to allRecents")
                    } else {
                        console.log("Item " + title + " already extists in allRecents")
                    }
                }
                console.log(allRecents);
            } else {
                if (!$('#emptyMessage').length) {
                    $('.list').append('<div id="emptyMessage" class="container center"><h4>Its Pretty Quiet Around Here,</h4><h4>- Nothing to Show -</h4></div>');
                }
            };
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                alert('There was a problem with the server.  Try again soon!');
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            setTimeout(worker, 10000);
          }
    });
})();
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Grid Content */
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.column {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.column-title {
    height: 8%;
    width: auto;
}
.info-container {
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    height: 23%;
    width: auto;
}

.center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align: center;
}

.when {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(82, 52, 52);
}
.what {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

#right-column {
    overflow: auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}

.list {
    height: 92%;
}
/* End Grid Content */

/* Fonts */
h1, h3, h2, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*display: block;*/
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

h3 {
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 2em;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
/* End Fonts */


/* Custom Colors */
.light-green {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.dark-green {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
.blue {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.crimson {
    background-color: crimson;
}
.darkorchid {
    background-color: darkorchid;
}
.orange {
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.background {
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
}
.transparent {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
/* End Custom Colors */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- The JSON data below must be linked to as a separate file to manipulate it while the HTML displays -->


<body>
        <div class="grid background">
            <!-- Left Column -->
            <div class="column transparent"> 
                <div class="center light-green column-title">
                    <h3>OVERVIEW</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="container blue center">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="count">5</h1>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Total Media</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="container crimson center">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="count">3</h1>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Movies</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="container darkorchid center">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="count">2</h1>
                    </div>
                    <h2>TV Shows</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="container blue center">
                    <h1>N/A</h1>
                    <h2>Used</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Right Column -->
            <div id="right-column" class="column transparent">
                <div class="center light-green column-title">
                    <h3>RECENTLY ADDED</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="list"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**JSON data file feeding the Ajax request**
It must me linked as a separate file and referenced in the function to work.
    `{
        "recent": [
            {
                "title":"Item 1",
                "added": "21:14",
                "type": "Movie"
            },
            {
                "title":"Item 2",
                "added": "11:19",
                "type": "TV"
            },
            {
                "title":"Item 3",
                "added": "07:46",
                "type": "Movie"
            },
            {
                "title":"Item 4",
                "added": "07:46",
                "type": "Movie"
            },
            {
                "title":"Item 5",
                "added": "14:05",
                "type": "TV"
            }
        ]
    }`

I always try to be as concise as possible, hopefully the demo at the top makes things clear, if not, I'd be happy to add more information. Cheers everyone.

Comment: Surely some must have an idea?